# Pandas rolling up column values based upon max value in column when aggregating

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem regarding my pandas data frame which contains row level for users, such as which group they belong to, their country, type, and total number of impressions from that user. An example slice of my df:

```
┌──────────┬───────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬──────────────────┐
│  userID  │ userGroup │ userCountry │ userType │ totalImpressions │
├──────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼──────────────────┤
│ Xn2r5u8x │ one       │ USA         │ premium  │             7454 │
│ fTjWnZr4 │ two       │ USA         │ basic    │              657 │
│ MbQeThWm │ two       │ USA         │ standard │              578 │
│ Xp2s5v8y │ two       │ JP          │ core     │            34509 │
│ gUkXn2r5 │ three     │ JP          │ core     │               43 │
│ NcRfUjXn │ four      │ UK          │ premium  │            85656 │
│ WmZq4t7w │ four      │ USA         │ core     │             3456 │
│ eThVmYq3 │ four      │ JP          │ standard │             7689 │
│ KbPeShVk │ four      │ UK          │ standard │            92834 │
└──────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┘
```

As you can see, the info is 1 row per user, where users in a group can belong to different country, type and different no of total impressions.

What I would like to do is roll this data up to the `userGroup` level, getting rid of the `userID`, keeping the `userCountry` and `userType` of the user with the highest number of `totalImpressions` , and summing up the `totalImpression` for all users in that group. This should result in a data frame like:

```
┌───────────┬──────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ userGroup │ groupCountry │ groupType │ groupTotalImpressions │
├───────────┼──────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ one       │ USA          │ premium   │                  7454 │
│ two       │ JP           │ core      │                 35744 │
│ three     │ JP           │ core      │                    43 │
│ four      │ UK           │ standard  │                189635 │
└───────────┴──────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

As you can see `groupCountry` and `groupType` are coming from the user within that group with the highest `totalImpression` rather than the first row value in a group.

Is this something possible in pandas, I know I could aggregate using `pd.groupby`, but from here I am not sure how to select the country/type of the the top user by totalImpressions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To generate my example data :

````
import pandas as pd 

lst = [['Xn2r5u8x', 'one', 'USA', 'premium', 7454],
['fTjWnZr4', 'two', 'USA', 'basic', 657],
['MbQeThWm', 'two', 'USA', 'standard', 578],
['Xp2s5v8y', 'two', 'JP', 'core', 34509],
['gUkXn2r5', 'three', 'JP', 'core', 43],
['NcRfUjXn', 'four', 'UK', 'premium', 85656],
['WmZq4t7w', 'four', 'USA', 'core', 3456],
['eThVmYq3', 'four', 'JP', 'standard', 7689],
['KbPeShVk', 'four', 'UK', 'standard', 92834]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['userID', 'userGroup', 'userCountry', 'userType', 'totalImpressions'])```
````

Comment: Hi, what was your attempts as code, and where did they fail at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort ascending your dataframe by the `totalImpressions` column, you just have to keep the last row for each group and sum impressions.

Use `groupby.agg`:

```
out = df.sort_values('totalImpressions').groupby('userGroup', as_index=False) \
        .agg({'userGroup': 'last', 'userCountry': 'last',
              'userType': 'last', 'totalImpressions': 'sum'})
print(out)

# Output
  userGroup userCountry  userType  totalImpressions
0      four          UK  standard            189635
1       one         USA   premium              7454
2     three          JP      core                43
3       two          JP      core             35744
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this seems to work, did not know that pd.agg could take `last` as an operation!